# AWS API Gateway simple way to copy complete url

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

[image]

Where can I get the full url to easily copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full URL to the invoke the top level resource is displayed as the "Invoke URL" on the stage detail page.  In the navigation tree on the left, click on Stages under your API.  In the Stages pane, click on the stage you want.  The Invoke URL is displayed in the blue bar at the top of the Stage Editor pane.  You can expand the stage and select individual methods to see their full Invoke URLs.